# How to change FlutterLogo image

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I was wondering if I could replace the default Flutter logo of the application with my own personalised logo instead?

```
new Column(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: <Widget>[
         new FlutterLogo(
           size: _iconAnimation.value * 100.0,
                ),
```

Comment: https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/

Answer (score 3):

```
 new Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
   children: <Widget>[
       new Image(
        image: new AssetImage("assets/example.jpg")),
   ])
```

add assets folder in root  than in pubspec.jaml

```
    assets:
     -assets/example.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
children: <Widget>[
    new Image(
    image: new AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
    width: _iconAnimation.value * 100,
    height: _iconAnimation.value * 100,
),
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

No ,you can't change the `image` in the `FlutterLogo` widget, this widget is only there to display the flutter logo to which you can only add the size or change the color or add some animations.

See : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlutterLogo-class.html

So,if you want to add a custom image, you won't use the `FlutterLogo` widget anymore but rather a **widget that will allow you to display an image** for example the `Image` widget or use `Image.network()` or `Image.asset()` to define your image.

See : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html